# Div in the bottom of the page with image under it

Tags: css, html

I have this div:

```
<div style="padding:5px 100px 0px 100px; bottom:5px; position:absolute">
<div class="divLine" style="margin:5px 0px 10px 0px;"></div>   
<div>     
    <p class="pull-right titleLink">© Ofir Messing 2013-2014 · <a class="titleLink" href="#">Link</a></p>
    <p style="text-align:left;"><a href="#"  class="titleLink">למעלה</a></p> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want it in the bottom of the page I tried everything. How can I do that?
***I have an image under it.*** 
http://jsbin.com/ginoveja/2

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`...

Comment: But now it's always down not only when I go to the bottom of the page. I don't want it to move with me.

Comment: It's like navbar in bootstrap just in the bottom of the page not in the top.

Comment: @user2998223 What is the image supposed to do? Can you provide a fiddle or at least a link to your site or show what it's looking like now and what you want it to look like?

Comment: I added a link in the question

Comment: @user2998223 I don't understand the question.  Can you please clarify: You want the div under all other content (besides the image you mention), or you want it to always be at the bottom of the user's screen?  Where is the image you mention?  Or are you speaking of the background image?  Can you create an image to show what you want the end result to be?

Comment: I want it in the bottom of my page like all other content but in the bottom of the page. the image is in background but i did it darker so it's no in the background-image property. It's like what this page have in his bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi just remove position:fixed it will solve the issue.

Don't position your images with position: fixed; for your current situation.  position: fixed; is for keep an element fixed on the screen so that it never moves. When you view your images on a smaller screen, the text must move somewhere, so it overlaps the fixed images.

I have verified it in Mozilla Firefox fire bug by removing position:fixed attribute, it was working.

Best of luck.

Comment: I did n't understand you properly.
Is that onclick event to show paragraph is there in the website that you have provided.
Please post your code for that onclick functionality so that we may look into that.

Comment: Never mind what you wrote solve the problem thank you.